# Ordering Data with Stacked Bar Charts in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Alternate title: replacing a continuous legend with a discrete legend in ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart using this code:

```
DataTest = data.frame(Order = 1:7,
                  Data = c(340, 464, 93, 218, 16, 206, 103),
                  Category = factor(c("Free", "Unavailable", "Free",
                                    "Unavailable", "Free", "Unavailable", "Free"),
                                    levels = c("Free", "Unavailable")))

ggplot(DataTest, aes(x="Thing", y=Data, fill=Category)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

Ignore x, it's unimportant. The plotted graph looks like this:

[Stacked bar chart with 2 blocks of solid colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0EXD.png)

The problem is, I want the data to be ordered like the rows in my data frame, so the stacked bar chart should be striped with alternating colours, like this:

[Stacked bar chart striped with alternating colours, but with a continuous legend instead of a discrete legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP6zc.png)

In fact, this bar chart is exactly what I want - aside from the legend. I want the legend to show just two colours, but I can't figure out how to set that up.

The code for this bar chart is:

```
DataTest[["Category"]] = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1) # change Category from a factor to numeric
ggplot(DataTest, aes(x="Thing", y=Data, fill=Category)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

The same as the previous snippet, but this time Catgeory is a numeric vector of only 1s and 0s.
If I use a logical vector instead of numeric, once again the bars are grouped by colour.

Here's one last thing I tried:

```
ggplot(DataTest, aes(x="Thing", y=Data, fill=Order, colour=Category)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

[Messy bar chart that has some order but is nevertheless grouped by Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWpj2.png)

Which shows that despite stat="identity", ggplot is insisting on sorting the data.

SO.

To be clear, I can't figure out how to sort my data by Order, but colour my data according to Category - except by introducing a continuous legend, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure that I understand your question. Wild stab at the dark here:

```
DataTest$gp <- seq(nrow(DataTest))

ggplot(DataTest, aes(x="thing", y=Data, fill=Category, group=factor(gp))) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! Is there a reason you turned gp into a factor? It doesn't seem to be necessary. And why does it stack even though you got rid of position="stack"?

Comment: The default of geom_bar is a stacked plot if the groups share on the same x-axis value. And yes, factor is not necessary in this case; but it's good practice to change the continuous variable (1, 2, 3, ...) into a discrete categorical factor so reduce confusion.